# Prove that the center of a group is normal.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

Can someone please verify this?

> Prove that the center of a group is normal.

let $G$ be a group, and let $\operatorname{Z}(G)$ denote its center. Let $g \in G$ and $z \in \operatorname{Z}(G)$. Then,

\begin{eqnarray}
gzg^{-1} &=& gg^{-1}z \\
&=& z \in \operatorname{Z}(G)
\end{eqnarray}

Since $\operatorname{Z}(G)$ is closed under conjugation by elements of $G$, $\operatorname{Z}(G)$ is normal.

Comment: @user154185 consider crafting your answer into a real solution below. That's allowed! People will let you know with votes what they think about it.